# Issue while using Docker API for GO - cannot import "nat"

Tags: api, docker, go, client, docker-api

I am trying to use the docker API for golang that is available from github.com/docker/docker/client. So far I am able to start the containers on the port that is predefined during image built. I am trying to map the port during runtime using the API; something equivalent to

```
docker run -p 8083:8082 -d myImage:1.0.0
```

I tried to do something like the following for mapping the ports:

```
host_config := &container.HostConfig{
     PortBindings: nat.PortMap{
     "8082/tcp": []nat.PortBinding{
         {
             HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
             HostPort: "8983",
         },
      },
   },
}
```

The problem here is that the variable "nat" lives inside the vendor folder of the API. I couldn't import something directly from the go vendor folder. Someone on the stackoverflow suggested to copy the go-connection folder into the github folder and remove the nested vendor directory. I did as suggested and created a path as follows:

`"github.com/docker/go-connections/nat"`

now I get the following error during compile time:

```
src\main\createcontainer1.go:53: cannot use "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet literal (type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet in field value

src\main\createcontainer1.go:65: cannot use "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap literal (type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap in field value
```

Have anyone faced this issue and overcome it? I am using the Go ver 1.8.

Comment: You can't have nested vendor folders, so you need to properly vendor your dependencies. Also, the import path is now `github.com/moby/moby`.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to do more than just copy it, you need to *move* it.  The same package located in two different locations are *different packages* to the go tool (because it can't guarantee they are identical, so it uses fully-qualified import paths).

If a package you're using has a vendor directory, and you need to use the packages in it, you have two options:

- Move everything out of the `vendor` directory in that package into your `$GOPATH/src`
- Vendor the package itself, and then move everything from the package's `vendor` directory into your project's vendor directory (`<project root>/vendor`).  This is known as "flattening" your vendored dependencies, and most Go vendoring utilities (ex. Govendor or Godep) can do this, either automatically or with a flag.  You can also do it manually, though.

The latter is generally the recommended strategy.  The important key, though, is that the package itself cannot have a version of that library in its own `vendor` directory, as Go tool automatically uses the deepest vendored version of a package that it can access.